# How to fix output from SQL Developer report with embedded html

Tags: html, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

[Output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFc6J.jpg)  I'm creating reports in Oracle SQL Developer that contain html embedded in the queries. The formatting results work correctly in the query output of sql dev. However, when I generate the reports and view them in Chrome, the formatting is not displayed, only the html code I used in the query.

I've tried various tweaks to the queries but can't seem to get the web page results to look like the query results (colored formatting).

```
SELECT NAME, 
CASE when TO_CHAR(Date1 - Date2, '00.00') > 2.00 
        THEN '<html><strong><font color="red" face="Calibri" size=5>'
           ||TO_CHAR(Date1 - Date2, '00.00')
           ||'</font></strong>'
        ELSE '<html><strong><font color="green" face="Calibri" size=5>'
           ||TO_CHAR(Date1 - Date2, '00.00')
           ||'</font></strong>'
        END Completion_Time_in_Days
FROM TABLEX
WHERE NAME = 'Brian Test2';
```

EXPECTED: 
Result appears in Chrome like it does in the query output. 
Ex: 
Brian Test2     COLORED_VALUE

Actual:
Brian Test2    ex:html-strong-font color="green" face="Calibri" size=5- 00.01-/font-/strong

Comment: 'generate the reports...' - how are you generating the reports? our grids use HTML3 to render the html tags in your query results. I wouldn't expect them to look the same in Chrome where HTML3 is...dead?

Comment: Hi Jeff, I'm generating the reports via right clicking the report under 'User Defined Reports' and selecting the HTML output option.  This returns the Chrome HTML Document.

Comment: any reason you can't share that report? then we can see what you see

Comment: Sorry, Jeff. Afraid I can't share that.  However, I did attach a sample image of what I'm seeing if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Putting HTML in the query to influence how it looks in a Data Grid is one thing - for instance...

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME ,
LAST_NAME ,
EMAIL ,
PHONE_NUMBER ,
HIRE_DATE ,
JOB_ID ,
CASE
          WHEN Salary > 5000
          THEN '<html><strong><font color="green" face="Comic Sans MS" size=5>'
               ||SALARY
               ||'</font></strong>'
          ELSE '<html><font color="blue" face="Comic Sans MS" size=5>'
               ||SALARY
               ||'</font>'
     END salary
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
fetch FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY
```

[image]

But, when you use the export feature to save this as an HTML report, that's not designed to accommodate what you've done above. It's sole purpose is to give you a decent rendering of your data grid in an HTML page

So strip out the HTML from your query, and then generate your HTML if you want, and update it after the fact, maybe with some CSS.

Or use another technology with Oracle APEX - you start and end with HTML then.

Comment: Great suggestions. I think I'll give APEX a go. Thanks, Jeff!  I appreciate your help as well as your blog posts.  Matter of fact, that data grid example you provided was where I learned I could embed html into queries to begin with!  Cheers!